# Bundle diameter calculation algorithm with different wire sizes accounting for twisted pairs?

Tags: algorithms, mathematical-programming

Based on the same question asked here: [Bundle diameter calculation algorithm with different wire sizes?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/159955/bundle-diameter-calculation-algorithm-with-different-wire-sizes)

Best answer was this: https://scipython.com/blog/packing-circles-in-a-circle/

However, there are wires in electrical design that function as a "twisted pair". Is there a way to alter the existing code above to specify that a particular pair of circles must be tangent to each other for this packing?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to state your problem in a self-contained way, so we don't need to click on links to understand what you are asking.  Coding questions are most likely not on-topic here, but you can ask about techniques, methods, and algorithms.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your model is no more just defined by circles then, because the pairs are twisted so that their relative orientation changes along the wire. So on every section you have a different problem, with a "circle pair" of given orientation. Either the other wires can come in contact with these to form a close packing, and your problem turns to true 3D, or you can consider the pair as a single cylindre in which the pair freely rotates. In this case, you are back to the initial problem.